# Question from Chapter Two of Axler's College Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering if you guys could help me with this question from Axler's "College Algebra":

Suppose (x1 , y1 ) and (x2 , y2 ) are the endpoints of a line segment.
(a) Show that the distance between the point
(x1+x2)/2 , (y1+y2)/2 and the endpoint (x1,y1)
equals half the length of the line segment.
(b) Show that the distance between the point
((x1+x2)/2 , (y1+y2)/2)  and the endpoint (x2,y2)
equals half the length of the line segment.

All I have tried so far is substituting numbers for x1, x2, y1, and y2. I cannot think of anything else unfortunately.

Comment: How do you find the distance between two points? You will need to do some algebra here.

Answer (score 1):

The distance between two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by Pythagoras' theorem:
$$ \text{dist}\left( (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \right) = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 +(y_2-y_1)^2 }. $$
Therefore, the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(\tfrac{x_1+x_2}{2},\tfrac{y_1+y_2}{2})$ is
$$ \sqrt{\left( \tfrac{x_1 +x_2}{2} - x_1\right)^2 + \left( \tfrac{y_1 +y_2}{2} - y_1\right)^2}\, = \, \sqrt{ \left(\tfrac{x_2}{2} - \tfrac{x_1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\tfrac{y_2}{2} - \tfrac{y_1}{2}\right)^2} \, = \, \tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 +(y_2-y_1)^2 }$$
$$\implies \text{dist}\left((x_1,y_1), (\tfrac{x_1+x_2}{2},\tfrac{y_1+y_2}{2})\right) = \tfrac{1}{2}\text{dist}\left( (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \right).$$
You should be able to use the same strategy to answer the second part of the question.